# PHP: converting fopen to file_get_contents?

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents, fread

I'm experimenting around which is faster and more efficient so I found my old scipt using fopen. How can I convert this to file_get_contents?

PHP:

```
class.......
$filename = 'test.txt';
$this->filepointer = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$length = filesize($filename);

public function read_name($length)
{
$name = fread($this->filepointer, $length);
return str_replace("\0", '', $name);
}
.....
```

can someone guide me how to convert it to file_get_contents?

Comment: `$filerecord = file_get_contents($filename);echo $filerecord;` try this.

Comment: did you tried what i said to you?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** :

```
$name = file_get_contents($filename);
return str_replace("\0", '', $name);
```